# 'Easy Table' Plugin has float issues

Tags: plugins

Good day

I am using the [easy table plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/easy-table) and I have a problem with floats with it:
Any content I add below the table floats to the right of the table.

Now I can solve this by using a

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

but isn't there a more 'user-friendly' way of doing it? That way my clients (with no html/css experience) can use the tables without problems...

Table Shortcode Code:

```
[table caption="Just test table" width="500" colwidth="20|100|50" colalign="left|left|center|left|right"]
no,head1,head2,head3,head4
1,row1col1,row1col2,row1col3,100
2,row2col1,row2col2,row2col3,20000
3,row3col1,,row3col3,1405
4,row4col1,row4col2,row4col3,23023
[/table]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the CSS the table uses. Right now it probably uses `float:left` values.

Use Firebug or a similar tool to check if this is the case, and try to edit the CSS.

Comment: thanks...but how do I clear the floats without using a div  after the table? Can I set it in the css or do I have to do it in in the HTML as well? - what I want to achieve is to edit the css only, so that my client do not have to add a clear div when he creates a new table...

Comment: You could try using `display:inline-block;` or table display elements, [explanation can be found here](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout).

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of Easy Table.

Add this to your CSS

```
table.easy-table:after{content:" ";display:table}
table.easy-table:after{clear:both}
```